# Поставить курсор в конец поля tinymce

Tags: ajax, tinymce

Всем доброго времени суток.
Задача - при загрузке данных через ajax необходимо поместить полученные данные как цитату в поле tinymce и затем переместить курсор на следующую строку. Делаю так:

```
jsondata='<blockquote>'+jsondata+'</blockquote><p>&nbsp;</p>';
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, 'text-form');
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddEditor", false, 'text-form');
tinymce.get('text-form').setContent(jsondata);
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, 'text-form');
```

Но курсор устанавливается в самое начало добавленной строки и сама не переносится на следующую. Как сделать? Версия tinymce 4.2.5

Comment: Ну вообще - это через `document.createRange()` и  `window.getSelection()` делается. Так как редактор работает через `div` - `contenteditable` и по другому установить позицию не покатит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему не вставлять контент через "mceInsertContent"?
editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, jsondata);

В таком случае курсор автоматически сдвигается на конец элемента.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function enter(){
  var fld = document.getElementById("fld");
  fld.innerHTML = "hello\n";
  fld.focus();
  fld.selectionStart = fld.value.length;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="enter()">press</button>
<br>
<form>
<textarea id="fld">
</textarea>
</form>
```